# SwiftUI - Set FocusState of TextField from outside

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

I have created a custom `TextField` to display and edit the title of items in my app. When a user creates a new item I would like to focus this `TextField` automatically `.onAppear` so the title can be entered immediately. For existing items the `TextField` should not be focused.

Is the only way to do this to hold a `@State` outside of the `CustomTextField` like in the example below? To me it seems there might be a more elegant way to achieve this without creating yet another `@State`.

Here's a bit of simplified example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = "Text"
    @State var focusOnAppear = false
    @State var itemID = ""

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Button("+ New item") {
                focusOnAppear = true
                itemID = "0"
            }
            Button("Existing item"){
                focusOnAppear = false
                itemID = "1"
            }
            Button("Another existing item"){
                focusOnAppear = false
                itemID = "2"
            }
        }

        CustomTextField($text, focusOnAppear: focusOnAppear)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 44)
            .id(itemID)
    }
}

struct CustomTextField: View {

    @Binding private var text: String
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool

    var focusOnAppear = false

    init(_ text: Binding<String>, focusOnAppear: Bool) {
        self._text = text
        self.focusOnAppear = focusOnAppear
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .foregroundColor(isFocused ? .red : .primary)
            .border(Color.gray)
            .onAppear {
                if focusOnAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.5) {
                        isFocused = true
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code does not relate to description - reading this I would imagine an array as model with List as representation, instead of one forcefully recreated view.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the model... the example is a bit crude but I think it gets the point across about how to set the `FocusState` of newly created views.

Comment: If example does not correspond to your real code you might get solution that will not work there.

Comment: I think this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/72092987/976628